# Pandas Merge - How to also merge different index columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge two different DataFrames on columns which names are different but the values are the same. For example,

df1

```
   name subject result
0   Kim       c   pass
1   Lee  python   pass
2  Choi       c   fail
```

df2

```
    name language  score
0    Kim        c     95
1  Hwang     java     85
2    Lee   python     97
3   Park   python     80
```

If I run `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='subject', right_on='language')` then I get

```
#2 Merge stu1, stu2 by key value
  name_x subject result name_y language  score
0    Kim       c   pass    Kim        c     95
1   Choi       c   fail    Kim        c     95
2    Lee  python   pass    Lee   python     97
3    Lee  python   pass   Park   python     80
```

but In columns 'subject' and 'language', I want it to have only one column between them. They are redundant.

Thank you!

Comment: Aside from the question, does it really make sense to merge on 'subject', rather than 'name'?

Comment: @mozway I guess not xD, this was just provided as a learning material for pandas here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try renaming the column:

```
out=pd.merge(df1, df2.rename(columns={'language':'subject'}),on='subject')
```

OR

drop column after merging:

```
out=pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='subject', right_on='language').drop(columns='language')
```